# IOS 15 Safari / position:fixed and addressbar at the bottom

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, mobile-safari

On a website with a messenger system is a very simple contenteditable div at the bottom with position:fixed.

On IOS 15 the safari has the default setting with the adressbar at the bottom.
If the contenteditable div has focus (keyboard showing), the contenteditable div is not full visible (only half) and if you scroll down, there is always a distance at the bottom.

I tried many solutions I have found on the web like:

```
env(safe-area-inset-bottom)
-webkit-fill-available
z-index
viewport-fit=cover
font-size:16px
```

Nothing of them worked. I made a very simple jsfiddle to show you the behavoior. Please open this page in IOS 15 / Safari with adressbar at the bottom and click in the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/8vxL51rh/

How is it possible to show the full div and dont have that distance at the bottom if you scroll down?

Thank you very much.